# In python, How to do the postgresql 'LIKE %name%' query which mitigate SQL injection?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

I want to execute below query,

```
select * from table where name LIKE %sachin%;
```

I created sql query in this way,

```
sql = "select * from table where %s like '\%%s\%'"
```

It gives me following error,

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 42
```

I want '%' symbol before and after the string.
How can I achive this? It should also mitigate SQL injection.

Comment: Try POSIX Regular Expressions. You can see topic here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use placeholders and generate the right-hand value of the LIKE in SQL like as follows.  The big difficulty is you are also expecting to pass in the identifier which means you will probably have to do something a little different:

```
sqltemplate = "select * from table where {} like '%%' || %s || '%%'"
```

Into this we fill in our identifier.  Note it is important to whitelist the value.

```
allowed_columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar']
if colname in allowed_columns:
   sql = sqltemplate.format(colname);
else:
   raise ValueError('Bad column name!')
```

Then you can use a placeholder for %s and it will just work.

```
conn.execute(sql, (searchval,));
```

Note:  In psycopg2, you use `%s` and `%d` for placeholders, and `%%` to represent a literal percent.

Comment: I tried this, self.cursor.execute("select count(*) from table where 1 = ?", (1,)) .                                                 Got error: LINE 1: select count(*) from table where 1 = ?     . Not working.

Comment: count(*), not count()

Comment: Ok so it turns out psycopg uses %s as the placeholder.  Answer updated.

Comment: Still not working. This works fine:  sql = "SELECT name FROM table where username like '%sachin%'" ,             but This doesn't work :   sql = "SELECT name FROM table where username like '%%' || %s ||'%%'" ;  self.cursor.execute(sql, ("sachin", ));    Doesn't give any error but not fetching desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **%** as the escape character.

```
sql = "select * from table where name like '%%sachin%%'"
```

For your case, The above query should work.